# Broadcast receiver stop

Tags: broadcast

In my app i've a broadcast receiver.

---

I received a message from **firebase**, this message send an intent to receiver.

The reicever update the state of app and after check if there is a condition the player start.

When my app was open from some time, th receiver go down.
When message arrive it do nothing.

Why this problema?
Thanks and sorry for my english.

the receiver:

```
class CustomNotificationReceiver(val presenter: OrderListContract.Presenter,
                             val ordstatsfilt: String?) : BroadcastReceiver() {
override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) {
    if(intent.action == "com.woocommerce.app.NOTIFICATION") {
        presenter.loadOrders(ordstatsfilt, forceRefresh = true)
        if (inlavorazione > 0) {
            try {                 
                var uri: Uri? = Uri.parse(ContentResolver.SCHEME_ANDROID_RESOURCE + "://" + context.packageName + "/" + R.raw.cha_ching)
                        ?: null
                Log.d("debugsto prendendo il file", "valore uri = $uri")
                //verifico l'uri
                Log.d("debugsto prendendo il file", "debudcprima" + uri)
                if (uri != null) {
                    Log.d("debugsto prendendo il file", "Sono dentro if uri")
                    if (!player.isPlaying && urice==0) {
                        Log.d("firebase", "sono nell'if")
                        player.setDataSource(context, uri)
                        Log.d("firebase", "sono nell'if2")
                        player.prepare();
                        urice=1
                    }
                    if (inlavorazione > 0) {
                          if (!player.isPlaying) {
                            Log.d("debugparte il file", "debugparteil file")
                            try {
                                Handler().postDelayed({
                                    player.start()
                                }, 5000)
                            } catch (e: Exception) {
                                e.printStackTrace()
                            }

                        }
                    }/*else{
                    if(player.isPlaying) player.stop()
                }*/


                    player.setOnCompletionListener {
                        if (inlavorazione > 0) {
                            if (!player.isPlaying) {

                                try {
                                    Handler().postDelayed({
                                        player.start()
                                    }, 3000)
                                } catch (e: Exception) {
                                    e.printStackTrace()
                                }
                            }
                        }/*else{
                        if(player.isPlaying) {player.stop()
                            inlavorazione=0}
                    }*/
                    }
                }
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

the intent:

```
 Intent().also { intent ->
        intent.setAction("com.woocommerce.app.NOTIFICATION")        //tag per l'azione
        //intent.putExtra("data", "Notice me senpai!")
        sendBroadcast(intent) //invio l'intent tramite broadcast
    }
```

...

message arrive, inlavorazione++ , send intent, receiver load from db, and play sound. After some time the reicever apparentmently don't stop. It doesn't update or play sound.

Comment: Show the code please, you can insert try and catch in to your code to see more details about error

Comment: I edit question